# Resetting a deployment with a lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

Good morning, first of all thank you for reading me and giving me your help.
I have a python code in which I try to restart a deployment (codisys-api-pos) namespace (qa)  of an eks cluster on amazon.
File: lambda_fuction.py

````
import json
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
import datetime

def restart_deployment(v1_apps, deployment, namespace):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    now = str(now.isoformat("T") + "Z")
    body = {
        'spec': {
            'template':{
                'metadata': {
                    'annotations': {
                        'kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt': now
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try:
        v1_apps.patch_namespaced_deployment(deployment, namespace, body, pretty='true')
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling AppsV1Api->read_namespaced_deployment_status: %s\n" % e)

config.load_kube_config("./config")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    deployment = "codisys-api-pos"
    namespace = "qa"
    v1_apps = client.AppsV1Api()
    restart_deployment(v1_apps, deployment, namespace)```

My config is...
...
user:
  exec:
    apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
    args:
--region
xxxxxxxx
eks
get-token
--cluster-name
xxxxxxxxxx
--output
json
--profile
xxxxxx
command: aws


The error is: 
[ERROR]    2023-10-10T15:43:41.614Z        [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws' ....

How can I configure my config to connect to my eks cluster? Thank you once again, thank you.
````